# How to connect my sql database with html web page and retrieve data from it?

Tags: html, mysql

I already created a my sql database "travel_guide" with the table "places". it has columns "ID" "name" "details". And I have  a html web site. I want to connect the database to the web page and retrieve place details from the place table by searching the place name in the search bar of web site. how can I do this? I'm new to this.

Comment: HTML alone has no mechanism for interacting with a database.  You'll need a language which does.  Likely a server-side language to interact with the database and generate the resulting client-side HTML.  There are many to choose from.

Comment: can I use java script or PHP script?

Answer (score 3):

step 1 your going to need to connect to your database

step 2 your going to need something to pass the values from your database into your html to display them.

So since your beginning I would suggest using php to pass values to and from your database.

To connect to your database your going to need to specify 4 things.
The servername
the username of the user you have created for your database
that users password
and the actual name of your database I have included an example below

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "Brendan7";
$dbName = "cars";

$conn = mysqli_connect( $dbServername , $dbUsername , $dbPassword , $dbName );
```

Now once you have connected you can make a SQL select statement to bring data into you html like so

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';



$user_id = $_SESSION["u_id"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE person_id = " .$user_id." ";
// $sql = "SELECT SINGLE `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'";
$conn = mysqli_connect( $dbServername , $dbUsername , $dbPassword , $dbName );
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "user_id: " . $row["person_id"]. " - person_id: " . $row["person_first"]. " " . $row["person_last"]. "<br>";
    $person_id = $row["person_id"];
    $person_first = $row["person_first"];
}
} else {
echo $sql;
}
$conn->close();

?>

 <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">First Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_first" value="<?php echo $person_first;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">Last Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_last" value="<?php echo $person_last;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="example-email" class="col-md-12">Mobile</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_mobile" value="<?php echo $person_mobile;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="example-email" class="col-md-12">Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="address" required=""  name="person_address" value="<?php echo $person_address;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_email" value="<?php echo $person_email;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">SSN</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="SSN" value="<?php echo $SSN;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>

<?php
            include_once 'footer.php';
            ?>
```